# Свойство background для usercontrol wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Есть юзерконтрол на основе `toolbar`. Как обратиться к его свойству `Background` (пробросить это свойство) из окна, в котором он размещен.

Comment: Опишите вашу проблему яснее. У UserControl'а есть публичное свойство Background, в чём проблема обратиться к нему?

Comment: И что это даст? Мне нужен background toolbara этого usercontrol'a

Comment: Ну, toolbar — это [стандартный контрол](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar.aspx)? Тогда у него есть публичное свойство `Background`, опять не вижу проблемы _обратиться_ к свойству.

Если вам надо обратиться снаружи UserControl'а, то вы что-то делаете не то. Не дело внешнего мира знать, есть ли внутри у UserControl'а `ToolBar` или нету. (Хотя экспортировать такое свойство можно, в принципе.) Опишите свою настоящую задачу.

Comment: Смысл вынести это свойство как внешнее что-то типа ToolbarBackground. Чтоб из xaml я мог установить его.
    <MyControl>
         <MyControl.ToolbarBrush>
               и тут определения ксти
         </MyControl.ToolbarBrush>
    </MyControl>

Comment: @Serega Isupov Обертку сделайте для background'a toolbar'a в виде свойства.
А еще лучше делайте бинд background'a toolbox'a к свойству UserControla

Comment: Можно подробнее про бинд бэкграунда тулбара к свойству юзерконтрола?

Comment: Пока сделал обертку, ранее что-то не получалось. Вроде так же делал. Не могу правда ответить на свой вопрос, не хватает рейтинга. Хотелось бы поделиться, вдруг кому нужно будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, попробуйте так:

1) `MyControl.xaml.cs` определите DependencyProperty `Brush ToolbarBrush` (знаете, как?)
2) В `MyControl.xaml` сделайте что-то наподобие

```
<UserControl x:Name="Self"... >
    ...
    <ToolBar Background="{Binding ToolbarBrush, ElementName=Self}" ... />
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Если у вас установлен `DataContext` на сам `UserControl`, можно обойтись без имени, и привязаться через контекст.

Comment: Спасибо, так пожалуй легче будет, может подскажете еще как стрелку расширения убрать, а то у нее цвет какой-то не такой?

Comment: Хм, какую стрелку?

Comment: Не знаю как объяснить, в общем когда не хватает места на тулбаре для кнопок, нажав на эту стрелку можно посмотреть те, которым не хватило место. %) немного запутанно получилось

Comment: А, понятно. Я бы не советовал изменять внешний вид стандартных контролов — люди к ним привыкли. Если уж менять вид, так полностью; для этого нужен хороший дизайнер (то, что делают программисты, обычно выглядит ужасно), и умение писать скины.

Comment: Но если и правда-правда очень надо, попробуйте свойство [`OverflowMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar.overflowmode.aspx).

Comment: Ну хотя бы цвет поменять, а то...

Comment: А `OverflowMode` не помог?

Comment: Почему-то не помогает. Для всех значений показывает эту стрелку...

Answer (score 0):

Обратитесь от любого контрола к методу [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.110).aspx).